# Sample Complexity Lower bound for PCA

Tags: optimization, information-theory, lower-bounds, statistics

I am trying to find (without success) a sample complexity lower bound for PCA. The concrete problem I am considering is -

$X_{1}, X_{2}, \cdots X_{n} \sim D(0, \Sigma)$ are $d$-dimensional vectors sampled IID from a distribution with zero-mean and covariance matrix $\Sigma$. Our objective is to compute an $\epsilon$-approximation, $\hat{v}$ to the top eigenvector, $v_{1}$, of $\Sigma$ with respect to the $\sin^{2}$ error = $1 - \langle v_1, \hat{v} \rangle^{2}$.

My starting point was to consider the optimality of the Matrix-Bernstein-based estimator mentioned here - https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.06929. However, I don't know how to argue that it is the best estimate amongst all possible $\hat{v}$.

So far, the only paper I could find which provides a lower bound is https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.07837. However, the example using which they prove their lower bound does not follow the data points being zero-mean and therefore doesn't seem valid for my setting.

Any help would be much appreciated!